# Passing directory names into a bash command individually

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

I have the following directory names:

```
/aaa
/bbb
/ccc
/ddd
```

And I want to run the following command passing in the directory names with just *ls*:

```
ls | composer show drupal/MY_DIRECTORY_NAME_HERE --available | ack versions
```

How can I create a one line command to pass in the directory name into this composer command in a loop?

Comment: Do you have issues with **this** loop or do you want to learn how to write a loop. Then, there are good [tutorials](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) out there, and you should try yourself first.

Comment: How do you want to pass the names? As command line arguments? or from a regular file (text file)? or how?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski pass it in via ls i should have been more clear. sorry.

Comment: Please see [Why not parse ls, and what to do instead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @Panki well this is assuming ls is going to output non-standard characters. I know for a fact this directory will always have only letters. ls is the easiest solution I can think up of on the spot. any other options would be great if you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you obviously want to apply the command to all of the existing sub-directories, the cleanest way to do so (avoids the issue of directory names with special characters) would be

```bash
for dir in */
do
   composer show drupal/"$dir" --available | ack versions
done
```

This will iterate over all non-hidden directories and symlinks to directories (due to the trailing `/` on the glob pattern) and execute the command on the current directory.

Note that this assumes the command accepts directory paths with trailing `/`. If not, a little shell string processing to strip that `/` will help:

```bash
for dir in */
do
   composer show drupal/"${dir%/}" --available | ack versions
done
```

---

**Additional notes**:

1. Of course, writing it as one-liner is also possible:

   ```bash
   for dir in */; do composer show drupal/"$dir" --available | ack versions; done
   ```
2. You can adapt the command to iterate over an explicit list of directory names, as in

   ```bash
   for dir in '/aaa' '/bbb' '/ccc'
   do
       ...
   done
   ```

   The quotes around the individual list items are necessary if your actual directory names contain special characters (but note that there are cases when that alone won't suffice, so the glob-based approach shown above is still the safest).

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
printf '%s\n' '/aaa' '/bbb' '/ccc' |
    xargs -I{} composer show drupal/{} --available |
    ack versions
```

or for any dirs from current directory:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
    xargs -0 -I{} composer show drupal/{} --available |
    ack versions
```

Comment: Note that it has the merit of calling `ack` only once on the concatenated output of all `composer` invocations which is probably preferable anyway.

Comment: However, the second one fails for directory names that start with blanks or contain newline, single quote, double quote or backslash characters.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
for dir in *(N/); do composer show drupal/$dir --available; done | ack version
```

The `(N/)` part are *glob qualifiers*, `N` for `N`ullglob so you don't get an error if the glob doesn't match any file, `/` to select files of type *directory* only. If you want hidden directories to also be included, add the `D` (for `D`otglob) qualifier.

Replace `/` with `-/` to also include symlinks to directories (like `*/` (which also works in other shells) does, except the expansion of `*/` also adds a `/` at the end of each file).

Here's we're running `ack` only once on the output of all `composer` commands,  as we don't need to run one for each. That also means that the overall exit status of that pipeline will reflect whether `version` has been found at least once in any of them. If you moved `| ack version` inside the loop, the overall exit status would reflect whether `version` has been found in the last processed directory which would not be useful.